Agrupación de datos duplicados
Resulta que tengo un conflicto a la hora de agrupar datos: tengo 3 registros del mismo usuario, únicamente cambia la columna "Comentario" y Fecha, tal como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

Quisiera que se agruparan los datos y me mostrara el último registro que se ingresó, en este caso sería el de fecha 12/09/2023 con el comentario 3. Muestro la imagen de cómo deseo que se muestre:

Resulta que investigando intenté con la siguiente consulta:
Select
  id_secretaria,
  secretaria,
  min(fecha_de_verificacion) as update_date
from fechasectocentral
group by id_secretaria
order by id_secretaria;

Pero me agrupa solo la fecha y no me muestra los datos correspondientes al registro. Adjunto la imagen que me arroja con la consulta anterior; se supone que si la fecha es 12/09/2023 el comentario correspondiente sería 3:


Esa consulta no corresponde a la última imagen. En el SQL que has puesto no está el campo comentario que si aparece en la imagen, lo cual me hace dudar que la fecha que aparece corresponde a esa consulta.

Muestra tanto la consulta como la salida como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Qué DBMS estas usando? Siempre usa la etiqueta de tu DBMS en tus preguntas de SQL, para que sabemos que dialecto de SQL hay que usar.

Estas pensando en agregar los registros, pero en realidad simplemente quieres elegir registros. Quieres el ultimo registro por secretaria. En SQL solemos hacerlo con funciones de ventana, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) o MAX(...) OVER (...) por ejemplo.
select id_secretaria, secretaria, fecha_de_verificacion, comentario
from
(
  select 
    id_secretaria, secretaria, fecha_de_verificacion, comentario,
    max(fecha_de_verificacion) over (partition by id_secretaria) as max_fecha
  from fechasectocentral
) con_max_fecha
where fecha_de_verificacion = max_fecha
order by id_secretaria;


Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estaba bloqueado, no sabía por dónde darle, si funciono con tu consulta y actualmente ya está operando mi sistema
